# How to define a dynamic module in powershell 7

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, winapi, powershell-2.0

I'm currently trying to migrate a powershell 5 script to a powershell 7 one.
The goal of this script is to load the win32 api in memory `using [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain` and assemblies.

Here is the code :

```
function New-InMemoryModule {
    [Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute('PSUseShouldProcessForStateChangingFunctions', '')]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]
        $ModuleName = [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
    )

    $AppDomain = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain

    $LoadedAssemblies = $AppDomain.GetAssemblies()

    foreach ($Assembly in $LoadedAssemblies) {
        if ($Assembly.FullName -and ($Assembly.FullName.Split(',')[0] -eq $ModuleName)) {
            return $Assembly
        }
    }

    $AssemblyName = New-Object System.Reflection.AssemblyName($ModuleName)
    $AssemblyBuilder = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly($AssemblyName, [System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess]::Run)
    $ModuleBuilder = $AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule($ModuleName)

    return $ModuleBuilder
}

$Mod = New-InMemoryModule -ModuleName Win32
echo $Mod
```

When i execute it on powershell 5, this is the output when ran the first time :

```
FullyQualifiedName : Win32
MDStreamVersion    : 131072
ModuleVersionId    : 8a94565d-3e53-4cdf-9b9d-ae6da
                     d1df4cd
MetadataToken      : 1
ScopeName          : Win32
Name               : <Dans le module de la        
                     mémoire>
Assembly           : Win32, Version=0.0.0.0,      
                     Culture=neutral,
                     PublicKeyToken=null
CustomAttributes   : {}
ModuleHandle       : System.ModuleHandle
```

And then the second time when the module is instanced :

```
GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319
```

But when i try to execute it in powershell 7, i get the following error :

```
Method invocation failed because
     | [System.AppDomain] does not contain a       
     | method named 'DefineDynamicAssembly'
```

Do anyone has any idea if the syntax or if the way i'm suppose to call it changed ?
I read the MSDN Documentation but didn't find anything.

I tried some GPTs queries but the script provided wouldn't load the win32 api at all..

Have a nice day !

Updated code :

```
function New-InMemoryModule {
    [Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute('PSUseShouldProcessForStateChangingFunctions', '')]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]
        $ModuleName = [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
    )

    $LoadedAssemblies = [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()

    foreach ($Assembly in $LoadedAssemblies) {
        if ($Assembly.FullName -and ($Assembly.FullName.Split(',')[0] -eq $ModuleName)) {
            return $Assembly
        }
    }

    $AssemblyName = New-Object System.Reflection.AssemblyName($ModuleName)
    $AssemblyBuilder = [System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder]::DefineDynamicAssembly($AssemblyName, [System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess]::Run)
    $ModuleBuilder = $AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule($ModuleName)

    return $ModuleBuilder
}

$Mod = New-InMemoryModule -ModuleName Win32
echo $Mod
```

Output 1 execution :

```
FullyQualifiedName : RefEmit_InMemoryManifestMo
                     dule
MDStreamVersion    : 131072
ModuleVersionId    : ca1f7586-b9b8-41ed-9d0a-fa
                     c37f7f080d
MetadataToken      : 1
ScopeName          : RefEmit_InMemoryManifestMo
                     dule
Name               : <In Memory Module>        
Assembly           : Win32, Version=0.0.0.0,   
                     Culture=neutral, 
                     PublicKeyToken=null       
ModuleHandle       : System.ModuleHandle       
CustomAttributes   : {}
```

Output 2nd execution :

```
GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False
```

I updated my code but it doesn't seem to build the module correctly, i tried various syntax and read a bit of doc but i wasn't able to load it correctly.
The end goal is to load netapi32 in memory and execute NetShareEnum.

Regards.

Comment: `DefineDynamicAssembly` is not available in .NET Core. But you could just use `Add-Type` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell 7, the `[System.AppDomain]` class does not have a `DefineDynamicAssembly` method, which explains the error. The `[System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder]` class has been moved to a different namespace.

you can use the `[System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder]` class from the `[System.Reflection.Emit]` namespace directly.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the answer, i will take the time to test it and mark the post as answered

Comment: thanks to @mkement0 for correcting me, I forgot the `Emit` in `[System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder]`

Comment: I updated in the post the code, with the last version using the new class / namespace, i couldn't load win32 i will post output

Comment: Yeah, don't read my last comment, i don't know why but i didn't get this bug after that, everything is working thanks !